# Why create custom init when ivars/properties can be set from outside the instance?

Tags: objective-c, variables, inheritance, methods, init

I'm reading an Objective-C book and I have a question that the book doesn't seem to really answer.

Let's say I have two custom-made classes.

The first class is called `ClassA`. It has both the .h and .m files of course. The second class is called `ClassB`. It also has both .h and .m files.

Somewhere in the code, 'ClassA' has this method:

```
-(IBAction)displaySomeText:(id)sender {
    ClassB *myNumber = [[ClassB  alloc]init];

    NSString *numberString = [myNumber storedNumberAsString];
    // storedNumberAsString is just a method that returns a string object that holds
    // myVariable.

    [textView insertText:numberString];
    //textView is a object  I created that just displays some text on screen.

    [myNumber release];
}
```

The book tells me that `ClassB` should have a method:

```
-(id)init {
    [super init]; //I know why this is done, the book explains it well.
    myVariable = 42; // I created this variable already in the ClassB .h file 
    return self;
}
```

Now, when in the Interface Builder I click the buttons I connected, etc. It works, the number displayed is `42`.

My question is, why do I have to create an `-(id)init` method for `ClassB`, if I can do the following in `ClassA`'s method:

```
-(IBAction)displaySomeText:(id)sender {
    ClassB *myNumber = [[ClassB alloc]init];
    myNumber.myVariable = 42; //I just do this to skip the -(id)init method.

    NSString *numberString = [myNumber storedNumberAsString];
    [textView insertText:numberString];
    [myNumber release]; 
}
```

Doing this, it still displays the same value: `42`. I can change it to whatever I like. So why not just use the `init` inherited from `NSObject` and just do the simple way `myNumber.myVariable = 42`?

Comment: I think this is just a bad example of using init

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that the value of the instance variable were something more complicated than an integer. Suppose it involved reading a string from a file, or getting some information over the network, or just doing some arithmetic. In that case, it wouldn't make sense to have `ClassA` be responsible for setting that value correctly. That would break the [encapsulation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OOP_ObjC/Articles/ooObjectModel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005149-CH5-SW10) that makes it useful to have separate classes in the first place.

In this extremely simple case, you're quite right, there may be no reason to have a custom initializer for `ClassB`, but *in general*, a class should itself be responsible for its state being set up correctly. Foisting that responsibility off on other classes means that those others need to know about the internals of the first, meaning the two may be too tightly coupled.

In some cases, the value of the ivar might be a piece of information that is known only to `ClassA`, or needs to be calculated based on such a piece of information. Then you should create a custom initializer for `ClassB` which receives that value, e.g., `- (id) initWithInteger:` This would become the ["designated initializer"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MultipleInitializers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH33-SW1), and you would then override `-[ClassB init]` to call it with some reasonable default value.

Comment: Thank you. Makes so much sense. 

I had to ask, I wasn't sure, and when I'm learning the language I want to cover all the bases of why things are done the way they are.

Comment: Glad it helped. Anything you still need filled in? I wrote this answer fairly quickly; it could perhaps be expanded.

Answer (score 1):

If instances of ClassB do not have to have anything initialized (other than to nil/zero), you do not need to create an explicit `init` method for ClassB.  In this case the question is whether setting `myVariable` to `42` is ClassB's [answer to life, the universe, and everything](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_%28number%29#The_Hitchhiker.27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy), or whether `myVariable` is just a field in ClassB that could be set to any value.

That is, the issue is conceptual, not of physical significance.  If conceptually the value `42` "belongs" to ClassB, then there should be an `init` method for ClassB that sets it.  If that specific value has more meaning to ClassA than to ClassB then some method of ClassA should set it.  If you do it "wrong" the code still works fine, but your design is slightly less elegant, slightly less extendable, slightly less robust.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a tricky issue. I was "brought up" to think that after a constructor (initializer) runs, the object should be ready to go. You should be able to safely call any method on it. Therefore, you need to set up any instance variables in the constructor for which 0 is not a valid value. I like to set them up if they have 0 values anyway, just for sanity, because I never want to bother to know the minute details of every language I work with, like whether they initialize instance variables to 0 automatically.

However, there are some arguments for not initializing some variables.

- The initialization is complex, like loading a file or getting data from the network. You want to keep open the possibility of creating an instance and waiting until you're ready to do heavy weight operations.
- There are quite a lot of instance variables that are configurable. Your options are to make a constructor with umpteen arguments, or make a constructor with no or a few arguments, and let the caller decide which values should be set to non-default values by property setters.
- You need to set up a whole object graph before you can meaningfully initialize a value. That is, initializing the value might have side effects that depend on other related objects. The best solution is to construct each object, then use property setters to set the relationships between objects, then use property setters to initialize attribute values.